# error while trying to parse JSON values

Tags: json, swift, api

I am getting an error while trying to access JSON data saying:

**Error:**

> Cannot subscript a value of type [[String: Any]] with an index of type
>   'String'

**Here is my code:**

```
    func parseData() {

    fetchedExercise = []

    let url = "https://wger.de/api/v2/exercise/?format=json&language=2&status=2"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: OperationQueue.main)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print("error")
        }
        else {

            do {
                if let data = data,
                    let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves) as? [String:Any],
                    let exercises = fetchedData["results"] as? [[String: Any]] {

                    for eachExercise in exercises
                    {
                        if let name = exercises["name"] as? String, let description = exercises["description"] as? String { // Cannot subscript a value of type [[String: Any]] with an index of type 'String'
                            fetchedExercise.append(Exercise(name: name, description: description))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

I have shown error within the code comment on the line at which it occurs.

Comment: I suggest you learn the Decodable and Encodable protocols asap. They make much easier work of this! https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the line:

```
if let name = exercises["name"] as? String, let description = exercises["description"] as? String {
```

to:

```
if let name = eachExercise["name"] as? String, let description = eachExercise["description"] as? String {
```